# Click on the link by class attribute as XPath

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am using **Selenium RC API .NET 2.44**. I know that i can click on the link with the following localtors:

1. XPath: `//a[contains(@class, 'handpoint')]` or `//a[(@class, 'handpoint')]`
2. CSS: `css=a.handpoint`

But why I have the opportunity to click on the link with

```
selenium.click("class=handpoint");
```

Is this a shorthand of XPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't work with this API, but I used a similar API.

You can get a specified element in 3 different ways:

1. Using XPath
2. Using CSS
3. Using some HTML attributes ( E.g.: `id`, `name`, `class` ) or tag names

   In JavaScript you have some similar methods ( E.g.: `getElementById`, `getElementsByTagName` ).

So, you are in the 3rd case. This is a different situation, not a short form of XPath.

Comment: OK, thanks. But which of the eight locators `(Identifier, Id, Name, Link, DOM, XPath, CSS, UI-element)` 3rd case refers?

Comment: It identifies all HTML elements that look like: `<tagName class="handpoint" otherAttribute="otherValue" ... >`. This is related to DOM, but Id for example is also related to DOM ...

Comment: OK, hmm, but syntax of the DOM locators is different or it is short form or it is the features of specific API, like for .NET

Comment: very good link when using xpaths http://test-able.blogspot.ie/2016/04/xpath-selectors-cheat-sheet.html